# Injecting property into bean

Tags: java, spring

i am trying to decalre a spring bean on a xml (Mule config file), and i've created a bean like that:

```
<bean id="IsActiveFilter" class="com.TimeLineListener.IsActiveFilter">
    <property name="isChatActive" value="${chatListener.isActive}"/>
</bean>
```

Now, my question is - how can i get tothe value of isChatActive from within the actual bean class?  i mean, can i just create a variable (private int isChatActive) with the name isChatActive and it will get whatever value the placeholder gives it? i mean something like:

```
public class IsActiveFilter{
{ 
private int isChatActive;
}
```

Will that work? if not, how do i use it?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a getter and setter and you are fine:

```
public class IsActiveFilter{

    private int isChatActive;

    public int getIsChatActive() {
        return this.isChatActive;
    }

    public void setIsChatActive(int isChatActive) {
        this.isChatActive = isChatActive;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class IsActiveFilter {
    private int chatActive;
    public boolean isChatActive() {
        return chatActive;
    }
    public void setChatActive(boolean chatActive) {
        this.chatActive = chatActive;
    }
}
```